# How could I change the CPU product name?

Tags: linux, cpu, hardware

My CPU is tagged as a 'Intel XEon' instead of 'Intel Xeon' which is making me troubles. Is there any way to change the name of it? I would like to change the "E" in "Intel Xeon" to be lower case.
My testing software won't let that go through. There is a mismatch between golden image and actual name of CPU.

[image]

Comment: Where is it “tagged” in this way?

Comment: You question is interesting, but a little bit incomplete. Which command have you used to retreive the 'tag'? What kind of trouble is it making?

Comment: lscpu 

Model name: Intel(R) XEon (R) ...

same thing with /proc/cpuinfo

My testing software won't let that go through. There is a mismatch between golden image and actual name of CPU.

Comment: Are you running inside a VM? Could you [edit] your question to include the full contents of the “Model name” line from `lscpu`?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a nasty hack and correct me if I am wrong but you can patch your arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c in the kernel source and recompile your kernel to report exactly what you want if your test program reads from /proc/cpuinfo.

By the time of writing this answer latest version of the file
http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c